# Is there a mistake in this proof of Hall's theorem?

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

I was going over a proof of Hall's theorem in my textbook (Diestel, 3rd edition), and there appears to be a mistake. Though, there's probably a higher chance that I'm mistaken about something. I would appreciate some input. Here's the theorem and proof presented.

[image]

[image]

I'm having trouble with the inequality part of the proof (indicated by the arrow).

Let's consider an edge $ab$. Then $G' = G - (a,b)$. Thus we've removed $a$ and $b$, and all their incident edges. Let us now pick a subset of $A - a$ and call it $S$. There are three kinds of $S$.

1. A set that did not contain vertex $a$, and in which none of the neighbors of $S$ contained $b$ (except a ofcourse). In this case, $|N_{G'}(S)| = |N_G(S)|$.
2. A set that did not contain vertex $a$, but the neighbor of one or more vertices of S contained $b$. In this case, $|N_{G'}(S)| \lt |N_G(S)|$.
3. A set that contained vertex $a$, and the neighbors of one or more vertices of S contained b.
4. A set thant contained vertex $a$, but none of the neighbors in $S$ contained $b$

2) Is the one I'm having trouble with at the moment. In this case, the inequality indicated in the proof doesn't hold since $|N_{G'}(S)|$ is less than $|N_G(S)|$.

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be assured that the "Second proof" is correct. It is in fact the "Proof of the Book" for this theorem.

It is a fact that for any $S\subset A\setminus\{a\}$ the set $N_{G'}(S)$ of "acceptable partners" $y\in B\ $ **is at most one** person smaller than $N_G(S)$, insofar as only person $b\in B$ has been eliminated. (Note that you should not count some number of edges, but the **number of persons** acceptable to at least one $x\in S$.)

Since at the particular spot in the proof we have assumed $\bigl|N_G(S)\bigr|\geq|S|+1$ for all subsets $S\subsetneq A$ we may conclude that
$$\bigl|N_{G'}(S)\bigr|\geq \bigl|N_G(S)\bigr|-1\geq(|S|+1)-1=|S|\ .$$

Comment: You're right. I can't believe I didn't see that before. It must have been because it was so late. Thank You for the answer. Also, on an unrelated note, what do you mean by "Proof of the Book"?

Comment: See the book *Proofs from the book" by Martin Aigner and Günter Ziegler.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ contains perfect matching of $A$ (and so will $G'$ to $A'$), and $G$ is a complete bipartite graph, then induction on $|B|$ will induce also $|A|$ but not vice versa, so if we induce $|A|$ and $|B|$ independently in different occurences, they will fulfill :

$$G - \{a\}   \rightarrow |N(A')|=|B|$$
$$G - \{b\}   \rightarrow |N(B')|\leq|B'|\lt|B|$$
because $|N(A')|$ doesn't follow $|A'|$ (still $|B|$) but $|N(B')|$ follows $|B'|$.

If we intersect both occurences the conditions follow with change on $|N(A')|$:
$$G - \{a,b\} = (G-\{a\}) \cap  (G-\{b\}) \rightarrow |N(A')|\neq|B|=|B'| \rightarrow |N(B')|\leq|N(A')|.$$

Now we add more assumption : if $|A|=|B|$ ($G$ is $K_{n,n}$) then $|N(B')|=|B'|=|B|-1$, so $|N(A')| \geq |B|-1$.

$|B|$ is $|N(A)|$ so $|N(A')|\geq|N(A)|-1$.

Then, if $G$ is a complete bipartite graph, $|N(A')|=|N_{G'} (S)|$ and $|N(A)|=|N_G (S)|$, so $$|N(A')|\gt|N(A)-1 \rightarrow |N_{G'} (S)|\gt|N_G (S)|-1.$$

You may find $|N_{G'} (S)|$ less than $|N_{G} (S)|$ if you assume $S$ contained vertex $a$, that's why the proof said $S$ must not be $A$ itself or any subset of it that contained $a$ both in $|N_{G'} (S)|$ and $|N_{G} (S)|$.